# How to access my ADSL modem configuration remotely over the Internet

Tags: modem, adsl

My ADSL modem at home is online.  Can I access its configuration page that is 192.168.1.1 sitting at another location, using the public IP address of my home modem?

Comment: Maybe, but it's impossible to tell because we don't know modem's model. But even if it's possible, you shouldn't do it. It makes modem susceptible to a number of attacks. Brute forcing password is pretty easy and many cheap modems have firmware bugs that can be used to extract password in a matter of seconds. After an attacker gets access to your modem's config, he can for example change your default DNS servers. This attack was used in Poland to substitute real bank websites with fake ones for users with vulnerable routers, some people lost lots of money this way.

Comment: You need a VPN connection to your home net (like openvpn). And you could use a dynamic dns like no-ip.com to update your current public IP-address.

Answer (score 1):

Find the User Guide for your ADSL modem and see if it supports the feature. Not all modems allow this kind of access outside of the LAN for security reasons.

If your modem does support the feature, the User Guide will tell you how to enable and use it. Still, as **gronostaj** says, it's a security risk and personally I wouldn't be enabling such a feature for that reason.