# How to access cable modem dashboard from laptop, when there is router in between?

Tags: router, routing, cable-modem

Obviously, when I connect cable modem directly to laptop using LAN cable I can access it (http://192.168.100.1).

But when router is between my laptop and cable modem it's obviously not as easy as that... what I am wondering if there is a general approach on how to solve this? Forward some port on my router so that when I http://192.168.1.1:8080 from laptop goes to http://192.168.100.1:80 on my cable modem? How would I configure that on my router?

Router: Asus N66U router with custom Merlin firmware

Cable modem: Motorola SB 6141

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem in my case was that I've designated laptop as [DMZ](http://event.asus.com/2012/nw/dummy_ui/EN/Advanced_Exposed_Content.html)... when I access 192.168.100.1 from other machines in my LAN, they can access cable modem dashboard.

Important thing to note, you must ensure that your router sets up LAN differently from cable modem network. My LAN on router is 192.168.10.1/255.255.255.0.

If I had 192.168.100.1/255.255.255.0 or 192.168.10.1/255.255.0.0 on my router, I would obviously not be able to access cable modem dashboard.

**Initial/Hacky SSH way:**

Hopefully, someone will post instructions on doing this in a better way (by configuring forwarding on router), in the meantime here is what I did:

1. SSH to router IP (I used Putty)
2. Once in command line type:

> ```
> content=$(wget 192.168.100.1/cmSignalData.htm -q -O -)
> echo $content
> ```

This showed HTML source of Signal page on Cable Modem dashboard, and it's easy to extract values from there. Obviously `http://192.168.100.1/cmSignalData.htm` is fixed path for Motorola SB 4121, for other cable modems you would need to figure out exact path to signal data by `wget 192.168.100.1` and then following HTML source.

Answer (score 1):

I'm confused why your modem would be behind your router, but yes you can do what you are asking by using port forwarding (as you thought you might be able to).

Please note that your question is likely misstated.

The reason why is that the diagram below is the general physical layout for a residential network.

ISP -> coax -> cable modem -> Ethernet -> Router WAN port
Router LAN port -> Ethernet -> ComputerA
Router Wireless -> 802.11 -> ComputerB

For your router you will need to set up port forwarding so that inbound traffic to the WAN port of your router on a specified port (e.g. 81) is port forwarded to 192.168.100.1 (your modem) on port 80.

To use that you would open your browser and go to the public IP address of the WAN interface on your router on port 81 (i.e. xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:81) and then your router will forward your traffic to 192.168.100 on port 80.

Instructions on how to configure Asus N66U port forwarding can be found at http://portforward.com/english/routers/port_forwarding/Asus/RT-N66U/Synology_DS213.htm.

EDIT: I have tested this same network topology and it works without problems for me.

Comment: It seems to me that he's misstating it. Routers must be behind modems, there's no other way to do it. Unless your router has a coax or phone connection, in which case you wouldn't need the modem. Additionally, OP states "But when router is between my laptop and cable modem"

Comment: Precisely my thought. In that case, the OP will need to verify that their modem supports remote management and if enable it. As discussed here (http://superuser.com/questions/872062/how-to-access-my-adsl-modem-configuration-remotely-over-the-internet) that is not always support for practical security issues.

Comment: True, though OP did also say that he can get to the management page when plugged in directly to the modem, so I have to imagine that it's enabled (and usually is, especially on the Surfboard line).

Comment: But that would only indicate that LAN management of the modem is enabled not remote management.

Comment: OP is trying to manage it over the LAN. OP hooks up a router, then connects internally to the router. Then cannot get to the mgmt page of the CM. OP is not trying to access the CM's mgmt page from outside the network.

Comment: I misunderstood what the OP was asking then, because I couldn't figure out how the modem would be behind the router and providing network connectivity to the WAN port of the router at the same time.

I think what the OP meant to say then was "How to access cable modem dashboard from computer, when the computer is behind router?" I have updated my answer to reflect that.

Comment: Your update more clearly reflects the problem, but it's not actually the case that the modem cannot be accessed once a router is hooked up. In fact, I've tested with several devices tonight and all of them still work on the private address of the modem (192.168.100.1). The only difference is what device has the public IP, even when the computer is hooked up to the modem directly and gets the public IP, it can assess the local address of the modem. The same happens when a router is hooked up.

Comment: Right but if the router WAN gets the public IP, then the the request from a computer connected to the router LAN has no way to be routed from private IP 1 (router LAN port) to public IP 1 (router WAN port) to private IP 2 (modem LAN port). Do you see what I mean?

Comment: I see what you think you mean, but it's just not correct. I'm in the exact environment you described, and it works for me to navigate to 192.168.100.1 from my computer (which is 192.168.9.25). Because of the fact that 192.168.100.1 is such a commonly used address for a CM or similar device, every single SOHO or personal router I've tested supports this. I've tested on 2 different higher end (one enterprise, and one carrier class device) and it it also works on both of those. I'm running a Ubiquiti ERL at home, and it works as well.

Comment: I tried it on an Arris modem and indeed you are correct. It works for me too. I can only then suspect it is a modem specific issue.

Comment: That's possible, but I do doubt that as well (just given what I know). Because 192.168.100.1 is a non-routable IP address, one would figure the router would have to know to try it out of the WAN port anyway. Generally speaking, I would figure that other non-routable ranges are dropped if there's no route available for them defined in the routing table of the router. Now, I don't know that for sure, but I can test it tomorrow to see if that's the case. The test is simple enough, statically assign a device 192.168.30.1 as it's address, hook it up to a switch outside the router (cont)

Comment: and also hook the modem into the switch. The router will get the public IP like always, then I can try and connect to 192.168.30.1 from inside my network and see what happens. I'll report back, because this is an interesting question about routing design for SOHO routers. It actually wouldn't surprised me if it worked, just as a mechanism for dealing with stuff like this.

Comment: Please do, I would be very interested to see what your results are.

Comment: Well, the routing table for my ERL shows 0.0.0.0/0 to be routed out of the WAN port as the default. This includes non-routable ranges, so I imagine that any device on a "private" IP (10. or 192.168) would also go out of the WAN port. But, the next hop address is my ISP's router, so I don't know by what mechanism a device would step in between that. I suppose it's possible that the ISP's routers have rules on them to send non-routable traffic back down to the client... I'll let you know what I find.

Comment: This diagram http://www.dslreports.com/forum/r20674896- discusses exactly what we are and why it works (either a static route or routing protocols). I just didn't think of traffic from a WAN port with a public address being routed to a private address on an upstream device. That is really interesting.

Comment: @user5870571 It seems title caused confusion - I wanted to describe situation in which there is outlet -> modem -> router -> laptop... so modem is "behind" router from "laptops perspective". I've updated the title to prevent further confusion. And, I've figured out the problem... see my updated answer: http://superuser.com/a/1034417/72793 . I'll upvote you guys anyway since your discussion helped me solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Have you actually tried to get there from the inside? Every single router that I've owned knows that if it's not the local network, it goes out the WAN port and takes care of it. I'm running a Ubiquiti Edge Router Lite right now, at home, and I can get to my modem just by putting in the address as if I were plugged into the modem directly. I've tested on the default N66U firmware, and it works (I happen to have one on hand), as well as Linksys default firmware, and an E4200 running DD-WRT, and another running Tomato (Toastman build). If you cannot, I would recommend opening a thread on Merlin's support forums, which looks to be mostly at Small Net Builder ([www.snbforums.com](http://www.snbforums.com/forums/asuswrt-merlin.42/))

I know that's not very helpful, but this should just work without port forwarding, and we can't troubleshoot specific things that may not work based on the whims of a CFW dev.

Comment: When I plug cable modem to laptop I can access dashboard by going to http://192.168.100.1 Router on the other hand is on http://192.168.10.1 . As advise I've tried going to that 100 address directly, when I am connected to router - and it's not working ;(.

Comment: Since posting this I've also tried on an enterprise Meraki device, and it just works. I have to imagine that it's something specifically with your CFW. I know Merlin posts at SNB, so I do think you'd be better off asking there, where the dev can give direct input and more users are running a similar firmware and can test theirs for feedback.